# Mechanism to strip specific tags from an XHTML document (but keep their contents)?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xpath, xquery

I would like a brief and easy way to strip tags from an XHTML document, and believe there has to be something curt enough among all the options like: XSLT, XPath, XQuery, custom C# programming using the .NET XML namespace. I'm open to others.

> **For example**, I want to strip all **`<b>`** tags from an XHTML document but
>   keep their inner content and child tags
>   (i.e. not simply skip the bold tag and
>   its children).

I need to maintain the structure of the original document minus the stripped tags.

Thoughts:

- I've seen **XSLT**'s ability to match elements for selection; however I want to match everything by default with a couple of exceptions, and I'm unsure it's conducive to this. This is what I'm looking at right now.
- **XQuery** I haven't started to look into. (*Update for XQuery*: Took a brief look at this technology and it's comparable enough to SQL in function that I fail to see how it can maintain the nested node structure of the original document - I think this is not a contender).
- A custom **C#/.NET XML namespace** program might be viable as I already have an idea for it, but my immediate assumption is it's likely more involved contrasted with the reasons for which these other XML-specific matching languages were created.
- ... another kind of **enabling technology** I haven't yet considered...

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short, simple and elegant XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to maintain the structure of
>   the original document minus the
>   stripped tags

Have you thought of XSLT? This is the language specifically designed for transforming XML and generally tree structures.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XHTML document, as the one below**:

```
<html>
 <head/>
 <body>
  <p> Hello, <b>World</b>!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**, in this case:

```
<html>
   <head/>
   <body>
      <p> Hello, World!</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had thought of XSLT, in fact just updated the question to relect that because I mistakenly called it XPath. However I couldn't think of a good XSLT for the problem. Apparently you have the solution. I will try it ....

Comment: @John-K: You are welcome. Please, don't hesitate to ask if there is something that needs to be explained. :)

Comment: ... works like a charm. Thanks. I'm using it via the XslCompiledTransform Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` is a bit too much for HTML/XHTML: `<pre>` elements will be cleaned. So I suggest to remove that line.